# Cannot connect to service fabric secure cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created new secure service fabric cluster on azure with cluster and admin client certificates in keyvault on azure. I installed the admin client certificate for current user and local machine stores but whenever I try to connect that cluster or explore it in browser its gave access denied error. I am also trying to connect from visual studio but it failed. In visual studio following is connection parameters:

```
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="my.end.point.com:19000"  
                           X509Credential="true"
                           ServerCertThumbprint="ClusterCertificateThumbPrint"
                           FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                           FindValue="AdminClientCertificateThumbPrint"
                           StoreLocation="CurrentUser"
                           StoreName="My" />
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check these articles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualstudio-configure-secure-connections and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having exactly the same error, I'm using the cluster certificate it requires you to create when you create the cluster the first time. I installed it on my machine but both the browser and VS doesn't wan't to connect

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar, my issue was that I had the wrong servercertthumbprint. I created my service fabric cluster as part of the visual studio publish step and in that case the configuration looked like this:

```
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="myservicefabricname:19000" 
                               X509Credential="true"
                               ServerCertThumbprint="certicateThumbprint"
                               FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                               FindValue="certicateThumbprint"
                               StoreLocation="LocalMachine"
                               StoreName="My" />
```

The thumbprint used for the local certificate and the service fabric one has the same certificate thumbprint.

Additionally, it seems that even though I added the ClusterConnectionParameters in the xml config, when I went "Publish" and expanded "Advanced Parameters" I had to manually enter the values.
[image]

In case you don't know how to find the thumbprint you can follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-retrieve-the-thumbprint-of-a-certificate